# Solve $\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} +t\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=1$ ...

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve this PDE using the characteristic form

$\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} +t\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=1 \\
w(x,0)=cos(x)
\end{equation}$

**My attempt**

We know $w(t)=w(x(t),t)$

Then by chain rule

$\frac{d w}{d t}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\times \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}$

This implies

$\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=t \\
\frac{d w}{d t}=1
\end{equation}$

Then:

$x=\frac{t^2}{2}+x_0$
$w=t+c$

This implies

$w(x,t)=c+t$...

Here in this step, i'm a little stuck. can give me a help?
Thanks

Comment: Where do you get $\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} = 1$?

Comment: When you compare the result of chain rule  with the PDE. You obtain that @AlexanderJ93

Comment: You are confusing $\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\text dw}{\text dt}$. The chain rule should read: $\frac{\text dw}{\text dt} =  \frac{\text dx}{\text dt} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}$

Comment: Yes, you have reason. Sorry @AlexanderJ93

Comment: I correct that, @AlexanderJ93

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve this PDE $\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} +x\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961021/solve-this-pde-frac-partial-w-partial-t-x-frac-partial-w-partial-x-1)

Comment: Not the same question... @Mattos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track here. You've found that $x-\frac{1}{2}t^2 = c_1$ and $w-t = c_2$. This means that the solution has the form $f(c_1,c_2) = 0$, or equivalently, $c_2 = g(c_1)$ for some arbitrary $f$ or $g$. Substituting in for $c_{1,2}$,we get $w-t = g(x-\frac{1}{2}t^2) \Rightarrow w(x,t) = t + g(x-\frac{1}{2}t^2)$ as the general solution.

Next, we can substitute the initial values to solve for $g$. Thus, $w(x,0) = g(x) = \cos(x)$, so $w(x,t) = t + \cos(x-\frac{1}{2}t^2)$ is the solution. You can verify this by substitution.